# Can a US-born child stay in India continuously for 180 days with an eVisa?

Tags: indian-citizens, us-citizens, overstaying, e-visas

My child was born in US and we are planning an India trip, and may not return back for at least 6 months. We do not have an OCI card for the child yet.

So we're planning to apply for the 1-year validity multi-entry eVisa and I wanted to know if the child can stay continuously in India for 180 days with this visa.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Is the child only an US citizen or also an Indian citizen because of the nationalities of the parents?

Comment: @Willeke India does not permit dual citizenship, [even for children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overseas_Citizenship_of_India#History).

Comment: @mlc: Not true. According to section 4 of India's Citizenship Act, a child born outside India to at least one Indian citizen parent is an Indian citizen by descent, if registered at an Indian consulate within one year of birth, with a statement that the child does not possess a foreign passport. Whether the child has foreign citizenship or nationality is not relevant. If an Indian citizen by descent has dual citizenship, subsection (1A) provides that they will lose Indian citizenship if they do not renounce their other citizenships by 6 months after attaining full age.

Comment: @mlc: The Indian embassy and consulates in the US do have [procedures](https://www.indianembassyusa.gov.in/extra?id=11) for registering and getting an Indian passport for children born in the US (who obviously must have US citizenship at birth, if not born to a foreign diplomat).

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of their parents' status, US citizens who are issued *multiple-entry* tourist [visas](https://www.mha.gov.in/PDF_Other/AnnexI_01022018.pdf) or [e-visas](https://www.mha.gov.in/PDF_Other/AnnexI_01022018.pdf) for India are usually allowed to stay up to 180 days at a time. Single-entry e-visas are usually only valid for 30 days. You should check the specific conditions printed on the visa or e-visa issued to your child to make sure that this usual practice is indeed applicable for them.

As you know, an OCI card allows unlimited visits to and stays in India, so it would be the more flexible option if it is available to your child.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for some urgent travel need and that's why couldn't wait for OCI. But just wondering if the child will be allowed to stay continuously for 180 days as I see in some websites it mentions as 90 days per entry and 180 days per year. Hence slightly confused if the child can stay continuously for 180 days.